# iPad: Compiler directive I can use to distinguish between Simulator and Device?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to have a compiler (pre-compiler) directive in my objective-C class to distinguish between the simulator build and the device build.

```
#if SIMULATOR
call testModule();
#else
call productionModule();
#endif
```

Is there such a #directive in X-code for the iPad/iPhone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
// simulator code
#else
//device code
#endif
```